# How to Remove or hide specific input field in WooCommerce Bookings

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I want to make these input filed remove or hide. It's anyway can do that?
[remove has person has resource checkbox and Requires confirmation and Can be canceled checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iowg.jpg)

[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bqdn.jpg)

[base cost and block cost input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNrDH.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have access to the site files so i made you a hook that hides what you wanted.

It only sets the element to display none so if someone will check the console they can still find them.

```
function bt_custom_admin_css () {
    echo '<style>

    label[for="_wc_booking_has_persons"],
    label[for="_wc_booking_has_resources"],
    .form-field._wc_booking_requires_confirmation_field,
    .form-field._wc_booking_user_can_cancel_field,
    .form-field._wc_booking_default_date_availability_field,
    .form-field._wc_booking_check_availability_against_field,
    .form-field._wc_booking_first_block_time_field,
    .form-field._wc_booking_cost_field,
    .form-field._wc_booking_block_cost_field {
        display: none !important;
    }

    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'bt_custom_admin_css');
```

You need to put this code in the functions.php in your active theme.

If you would like to disable it you can just comment the `add_action('admin_head', 'bt_custom_admin_css');`

If you see that there are still elements that you want to hide that i missed let me know.